# Trying to get my matrix printed not the heap address

Tags: java, matrix, heap-memory

The code seems to run except what I am getting is not a matrix of a specified (by the user) size but what I think is a heap address
Here's what it returns when the user inputs 2 for the size and then 4 numbers:

Enter matrix size: 
2
Enter a 2 by  2 matrix row by row: 2 3 4 5
The row-sort matrix is...[[D@3c954549BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 seconds)

here is the code....thank you in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise7_26M {

   public static void main (String[]args)


   {
           //Prompt user for input of matrix size


       System.out.println("Enter matrix size: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  
    int size = input.nextInt();
    double[][] m = new double [size][size];

    //prompt user for input of array
     System.out.print("Enter a " + size + " by  " + size + " matrix row by row: ");
     for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++)
           for (int column = 0; column < 2; column++)
               m[row][column] = input.nextDouble();

               System.out.print("The row-sort matrix is..." + m);


   }
```

Comment: `for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++)` explain what you think that line of code does?

Comment: No built-in pretty printer for matrix, loop through values and print them.

Comment: You already asked how to do this in another question for Arrays the same answer applies here.

Comment: If I asked that question before it was so long ago I cannot find it. I did look before asking. I thought the "for" line put the input numbers into rows. I am still pretty new at this. If you can't post the link to the original answer I will look for it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java arrays do not override `toString()` so you are getting the default implementation from `Object`. Instead, you can use [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object[]%29) like

```
System.out.println("The row-sort matrix is..." + Arrays.deepToString(m));
```